# 2048 Game //Java

Tags: java, разработка-игр, gui, случайные-числа

Нужно поставить двойку в случайний пустой **JLabel** по нажатию на кнопку "Start"

[image: PANEL]

Comment: а что Вы сделали?

Comment: @Tsyklop Пока только разметил панель.

Comment: У вас массив? сколько на сколько? 4*4 ?

Comment: @Dred фишка в том что я пишу через странно, хочу обойтись лэйблами

Answer (score 1):

Если я понимаю правильно, то у вас панель 4*4, тогда у вас должно быть что-то типа

```
int x = new Random().nextInt(4);
int y = new Random().nextInt(4);
int[][] array = new int[4][4];
array[x][y] = 2;
```

Вместо массива `int` применяете свои объекты. Но заполнение будет примерно так. В значение JLabel вносите 2 по такому принципу